# Trying to seed Neo4j cluster from backup

Tags: google-cloud-platform, neo4j, google-kubernetes-engine

Earlier running a single vm instance of neo4j. Now we have to move it to GKE. On GKE, I'm not able to restore the neo4j db. Following the [official](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/unbind/) documentation, I'm not able to stop the neo4j or unbind the same.
Running version 4.2.2

Can share few steps to restore from vm to GKE, that would be great help.

Comment: To clarify, this instance with neo4j was in your local environment or it was on GCE? Wiill you use any specific GKE version? 
Main issue is that you cannot create this backup from your first VM? Applyin it in GKE is another part?

Comment: With what exactly error you have? What command did you use?

Comment: I used GCE with Neo4j Enterprise edition. I was able to create backup and able to create database dump as well. So according to [this](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/clustering/seed/) I'm not able unbind the server. When I run the command inside the contianer 'neo4j-admin unbind' it didn't accept at all. That command doesn't exist. For GKE, we are using private cluster, And it's above the version 1.17 @PjoterS